# Keying in inputs into functions starting with 0

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

So I wrote a binary adder that takes 2 binary numbers as its input and returns their added binary value.

The problem is if i key in a binary such as 0100 it would return an error stating invalid token, is there any other way to overcome this, other than **inputting them as strings**?

for instance, I do not want it to be binary_add('11011','00100')

Comment: Binary format integer literals in Python can be written as `0b0100`, if that's what you mean?

Comment: `x = int(input("binary #:"), 2)`

Comment: numbers are numbers - binary is the representation. what exactly are you trying to do? also, `print(bin(x))`...